# NO iOS 14.6 Simulator Found Anywhere

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I developed an app for a client in React Native. I fixed it for all the versions Apple said it didn't work on, except 14.6.

Apple is saying the app doesn't work on 14.6. However, I can't find the 14.6 Simulator anywhere!

I've also tried downloading Xcode 13 beta, but the Simulator versions skip 14.6 (it goes 14.5 and then 15.0). I've also tried it on the latest 12.5 version (12.5.1). Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: It does seem crazy. But you could assume that if it works on 14.5 it works on 14.6. Either that or check it by building to your phone.

Comment: Ya, it does work on 14.5 and even 15.0. I thought it was strange it didn't work on 14.6.

Comment: Have you built to your device? My iPhone is on 14.6.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an iPhone.

Comment: It seems that Apple has released the iOS 14.6 but no simulator. The latest 12.x Xcode includes the 14.5 simulator. The only option is to test it on a real device. If you do not have a device there are online services where you can install and run your app in a real device and stream the screen in your browser. Some like amazon device farm has a free tier you can try, check the devices they have here https://awsdevicefarm.info/  .

Comment: Thanks. This almost works, but I don't see how I can run a React Native app on these online simulators. I guess Apple makes you run an app on the actual device before your submit, and I'll just have to find a Mac to try it on, or hire someone who can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: The way to run an app build with any technology stack on AWS Device Farm is the same for deploying a build in a device. You create the ipa and upload it, more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian Bartyczak Except for the new contact information after AirTag is lost, iOS14.6 does not bring other new features. Obviously, this time iOS14.6 is for iOS14.5.1 users. You are sure that you can’t complete the test on the 14.5 system.
i wish i can help you

Comment: @Adrian Bartyczak Apple’s official description also does not provide a 14.6 emulator, refer to (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683114), very regrettable.

Comment: Hey @M_JSL, thanks for this. It's good to know I'm not the only one with this issue. Yes, it is regrettable. I guess Apple forces you to test on an actual device, which is kind of unfair.

Comment: I think so,they recommend testing on a real device.